# Jasper Reports Two records in detail band instead of one?

Tags: subquery, jasper-reports

I am using the follwing sql with a subquery in jasper reports. The result is one record per id, but in the report there are always two records withe the same date.

The output in the Report is:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xGNY.png)

But it should be like that[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ1M8.png)

Answer (score 0):

SQL SELECT DISTINCT should prevent your query from returning duplicate results. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Otherwise (assuming every row is duplicated) a Print When Expression of ($V{REPORT_COUNT} % 2) != 0 will hide every second row. (Be aware that Variables used to sum your values will also need to be adjusted.)

There are plenty other solutions. Please update your question with ideally a  minimal jasper file showing both your query and issue for a more specific answer.